# Mongodb: Count specific objects in collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to count specific objects if present in collections like:

```
{
  id: 1,
  obj1: {...},
  obj2: {...}
},{
  id: 2,
  obj2: {...}
},{
  id: 3,
  obj1: {...},
  obj3: {...}
}
```

In above example i need the sum of count of objects(i.e. obj1, obj2, obj3). And query should return 5 in above scenario.

Comment: these are always named obj1, obj2, obj3? Three of them?

Comment: yes, names will always be same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below `$group` aggregation.

`$cond` with `$ifNull` expression to check for existence of field, output 1 when present 0 when absent.

inner `$sum` to count values in each document with outer `$sum` to sum the values across collection.

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {
    "$group":{
      "_id":null,
      "count":{
        "$sum":{
          "$sum":[
            {"$cond":[{"$ifNull":["$obj1",false]},1,0]},
            {"$cond":[{"$ifNull":["$obj2",false]},1,0]},
            {"$cond":[{"$ifNull":["$obj3",false]},1,0]}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I have replaced inner sum with add and it worked as needed, thanks